# Finding direction of induced EMF

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-induction

How should I find out the direction of the EMF induced in a rod of any length $l$ rotating with an angular speed $w$ in a region of magnetic field (perpendicular to the plane of the rotating rod) clockwise?

Is this one of those cases where I have to use the right- or the left-hand rule?

Comment: EMF is scalar number it has only two "directions"; either it pushes the current out of the center, or towards the center. Do you know how to find direction of magnetic force on mobile charge carriers in the rod? It depends on their velocity, magnetic field and sign of charge.

Answer (score 0):

One way to find the direction of the emf, or the direction of current flow if you were to form a loop by connecting the two ends of the rod, is to use the Lorentz force law. The current flow would be in the direction of the magnetic component of the Lorentz force:
$$\vec{f}_{mag} = \vec{v}\times\vec{B}$$
where $\vec{f}_{mag}$ is the magnetic force per unit charge. This is often the simpler approach when there is no physical loop involved.

Alternatively, you can view the rod as being part of an otherwise stationary loop. Depending on how you draw or imagine such a loop, the magnetic flux though the loop will be increasing or decreasing as the rod rotates. Then, by Lenz's law, the current flow will be in the direction that opposes the change in the magnetic flux through the loop.